# Android App skipping >300 frames

Tags: android, gridview, android-studio

My app is skipping >300 frames because it is doing too much work on its main thread. This happened after I implemented a Gridview showing pictures and by clicking on them they maximize to full screen. If i reduce the size of the images it gets better but for the final app it is planned to have some more images than right now, so I think this is not the way to go.
Also I have another question: I would like to have a specific text for each image when I maximize it. Basically I click on the small image in the gridview, it gets maximized in my full screen activity and a text field pops up. Is there any way to realize that?

Let me know if you need any further information.

Code for the gridview:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    }
    else
    {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.eich, R.drawable.hase,
        R.drawable.hase2, R.drawable.katze,
        R.drawable.wasch, R.drawable.wauwau,
        R.drawable.erd, R.drawable.wauwau,
        R.drawable.eich, R.drawable.hase,
        R.drawable.hase2, R.drawable.katze,
        R.drawable.wasch, R.drawable.katze,
        R.drawable.wauwau

};
```

And here the code for the full screen view:

```
public class FullViewActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_view);

    ImageButton back = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent BackToGrid = new Intent(FullViewActivity.this, GridViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(BackToGrid);
        }
    });

    Intent i = getIntent();

    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.FullView);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
}
```

Comment: Basically you should load bitmap on non ui thread (setImageResource call is the problem)... Find some image loader library and use it...

Comment: If I use a library does the app require a permanent internet connection to function propely?

Comment: i don't know - obviously it depends on library ... but logicaly it should not need it ...